# Community wiki function?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Several times, I've seen people on meta RPG make comments about clutter on community wiki. Is there some special wikipedia-esque function that works specifically with this flag for browsing and editing? I understand how it works w.r.t. voting and editing responses

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Community Wiki mean?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-does-community-wiki-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) over on meta.stackoverflow. Short form:

- voting doesn't affect rep
- lower rep level needed to edit original post
- post is owned by the Community User, not the original poster

There are a bunch more details over there, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you search on "wiki:1" it shows you Community Wiki entries (wiki:0 shows you non-CW ones).